# How to restrict directory name creation to pattern?

Tags: filesystems, directory, freebsd, account-restrictions

I have FreeNas `CIFS` share. Mount command result:

```
/dev/ufs/VSPHERE on /mnt/VSPHERE (ufs, NFS exported, local, soft-updates, nfsv4acls)
```

I want to restrict users from creating directories that do not fit to pattern: `YYYY-MM-DD` (year-month-day).

Users are using Windows to access CIFS share from network on `\\freenas\cifs\`. They see `\\freenas\` in network places. They go to `\CIFS\foo\` directory, then they can create any directory they want. That's is the problem. They should have create directory that meets `YYYY-MM-DD` pattern.

Users don't need to login to access this share, it's using FreeBSD `ftp:nogroup` account so I can apply restriction to that user in FreeBSD directly (FreeNas)?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Question edited, I hope it is more clear now. Thanks for remarks!

Comment: I don't see a way to do it except remove write permission from the root directory and providing a separate channel to create directories.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: No such method. You cannot restrict file/directory names. Create a separate directory and allow users access only to that directory. Instruct the users to follow that pattern only.